# I want to replace the calculation in the diagonal direction more concisely

Tags: css

I wrote a CSS that displays such a diagonal background. The `.parent::before` that displays the background here does not overflow the `.parent` even when it is slanted by changing the size in advance.

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: calc(100vw * 0.12) 0;
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent:before {
  background: blue;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(6deg);
  width: 200vw;
  height: calc(100% - 0.11 * (0.11 * 50% + 50vw) * 2);
  top: calc(0.11 * (0.11 * 50% + 50vw));
  left: -50vw;
  z-index: -1;
}

.parent:nth-child(2)::before {
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(-6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Content text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Content text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text</div>
</div>
```

**Question**

However, this complex calculation by `calc` seems to be difficult to read and understand the principle immediately and to change the code.

So I thought about replacing this behavior with simpler CSS, but I couldn't find a way to adjust the `height` as described above. Is there a concise way to replace the above complex CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider multiple gradient where it's easier to manipulate:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 12vw 0;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top    left, transparent 49%,#fff 50%) top   ,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,#fff 50%) bottom,
    red;
  background-size:100% 12vw;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.parent:nth-child(2) {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 49%,#fff 50%) top  ,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,transparent 49%,#fff 50%) bottom,
    blue;
  background-size:100% 12vw;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Content text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Content text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text</div>
</div>
```

Or use `clip-path` where you can have transparency

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 12vw 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
.parent:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:red;
  clip-path:polygon(0 12vw,100% 0,100% calc(100% - 12vw), 0 100%);
}

.parent:nth-child(2)::before {
  background:blue;
  transform:scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Content text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Content text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can it adjust the background rotation angle?

Comment: @mayard what angle? there is no rotation but 2 white triangles on the top of the background that you can control with background-size

Comment: @.Temani Afif The rotation angle around the center of the background of .parent::before. If this rotation angle is controlled by background-size, do I need to calculate for triangles with that angle?

Comment: @mayard you don't need any calculation, that's why I am giving those solutions. As you can see, the background-size use the padding to set the height of each triangle. Same logic with the clip-path where I am using the value of padding. This will give you the intended result without complex calculation

Comment: @.Temani Afif I noticed that I can get the height from the base and angle. Certainly this has become easier. Thank you very much!